# Cannot redirect url with dynamic segment

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect this url: `https://example.com/static/dynamic` to this: `https://example.com/en/static/dynamic`. As you can see I need to add the locale prefix, only the "dynamic" segment is variable, so I did:

```
RewriteRule ^(static/.*)$ /en/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but this doesn't redirect. The redirect mod is enabled, other redirects actually works .. but this doesn't redirect at all.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, make sure you restarted the http server after making changes, that you do test requests using a fresh anonymous browser window and that you correctly use the `AllowOverride` directive. Take a look into your http server's error log if you see something related to your test requests. Change that configuration file where you implemented that rule and change it to contain a definited syntax error, so nonsense. Restart the http server and check the error log file again. No entry, then your file does not get used, maybe it is stored at the wrong location or your forgot to enable such files.

Comment: The apache http server brings a feature called "rewrite logging". You can use it to make the server log every single step that is performed inside the rewriting engine into a log file. That allows to understand on a detailed level what is actually going on with your requests.

Comment: Also open your browser's console and the network tab in there. Then make a test request. What response do you see for that request?